# (Server Error): ReferenceError: playlistLists is not defined (next js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Please, Help me to get rid of this. I'm a newbie in react. I'm trying to create a filter gallery. When I called json file directly It works fine.

```
import playlistLists from "../pages/api/universities.json";

universities.json codes

[

    {
        "id": "1",
        "path": "/",
        "image": "/assets/images/universities/konstanz.png",
        "name": "University of Konstanz",
        "category": "Research University",
        "location": "Konstanz, Germany",
        "type": "Public",
        "area": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "path": "/",
        "image": "/assets/images/universities/cambridge.png",
        "name": "University of Cambridge",
        "category": "Research University",
        "location": "Cambridge, UK",
        "type": "Public",
        "area": "UK"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "path": "/",
        "image": "/assets/images/universities/trinity.png",
        "name": "Trinity College Dublin",
        "category": "Research University",
        "location": "Dublin, Ireland",
        "type": "Public",
        "area": "Ireland"
    }
]
```

But When I called this file with getStaticprops() like below way it's not working. Showing this error. I tried many times but can't solving it.

[image]

```
import { universities } from '../pages/api/universities';

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    return {
        props: {
            playlistLists: universities,
        },
    };
};
```

universities codes:

```
export const universities = [

    {
        "id": "1",
        "path": "/",
        "image": "/assets/images/universities/konstanz.png",
        "name": "University of Konstanz",
        "category": "Research University",
        "location": "Konstanz, Germany",
        "type": "Public",
        "area": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "path": "/",
        "image": "/assets/images/universities/cambridge.png",
        "name": "University of Cambridge",
        "category": "Research University",
        "location": "Cambridge, UK",
        "type": "Public",
        "area": "UK"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "path": "/",
        "image": "/assets/images/universities/trinity.png",
        "name": "Trinity College Dublin",
        "category": "Research University",
        "location": "Dublin, Ireland",
        "type": "Public",
        "area": "Ireland"
    }
];
```

Here is my main Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { RiMapPin2Line } from "react-icons/ri";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Pagination, Navigation, Autoplay } from "swiper";
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

// import playlistLists from '../pages/api/universities.json';

import { universities } from '../pages/api/universities';

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    return {
        props: {
            playlistLists: universities,
        },
    };
};


const allSuggestedUniversities = ['Worldwide', ...new Set(playlistLists.map(suggestedItem => suggestedItem.area))];

const SuggestedUniversities = ({ playlistLists }) => {


    const [suggestedItems, setSuggestedItems] = useState(playlistLists);

    const [suggestedFilterBtn, setSuggestedFilterBtn] = useState(allSuggestedUniversities);
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

    const filter = (button) => {

        if (button === 'Worldwide') {
            setSuggestedItems(playlistLists);
            return;
        }

        const filteredData = playlistLists.filter(suggestedItem => suggestedItem.area === button);
        setSuggestedItems(filteredData);
    }


    return (
        <section className="suggested section-space-top">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="universities">
                    <div className="universities__head">
                        <h2>Suggested Universities</h2>
                        <div className="universities__buttons">
                            <div className="universities__buttons__inner">
                                {
                                    suggestedFilterBtn.map((cat, index) => {
                                        return <button type="button" key={index} onClick={() => { filter(cat); setSelectedIndex(index); }} className={"filter-btn" + (selectedIndex === index ? " filter-btn-active" : "")}>{cat}</button>
                                    })
                                }
                                <Link href="/admission">
                                    <a className="filter-btn">More</a>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="universities__items">
                            <div className="universities__item-wrapper">
                                <Swiper
                                    spaceBetween={24}
                                    slidesPerView={"auto"}
                                    slidesPerGroup={1}
                                    loop={true}
                                    loopFillGroupWithBlank={true}
                                    navigation={false}
                                    modules={[Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation]}
                                    className="mySwiper"
                                    autoplay={{
                                        delay: 2000,
                                        disableOnInteraction: false,
                                    }}

                                >
                                    {
                                        suggestedItems.map((suggestedItem, index) => {
                                            return (
                                                <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                                                    <div className="universities__item">
                                                        <div className="universities__item__thumb">
                                                            <Link href={suggestedItem.path}>
                                                                <a>
                                                                    <Image src={suggestedItem.image} layout="fill" alt='image' />
                                                                </a>
                                                            </Link>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="universities__item__content-wrapper">
                                                            <div className="universities__item__content">
                                                                <h3>
                                                                    <Link href="/admission">
                                                                        <a>{suggestedItem.name}</a>
                                                                    </Link>
                                                                </h3>
                                                                <p className="primary-text">{suggestedItem.category}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="universities__item__info">
                                                                <div className="location">
                                                                    <RiMapPin2Line />
                                                                    <p className="primary-text">{suggestedItem.location}</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div className="tag">
                                                                    <p className="secondary-text">{suggestedItem.type}</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </SwiperSlide>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </Swiper>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default SuggestedUniversities;
```

If anyone help me to get rid of these I'll be very very thankful.

Comment: Indeed `playlistLists` is only available in `SuggesteUniversities`scope. Try to move `const allSuggestedUniversities = ['Worldwide', ...new Set(playlistLists.map(suggestedItem => suggestedItem.area))];` inside `SuggestedUniversities` function

Comment: Many many thanks for your suggestion. I did this. but it showing  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). Can you please help me to get rid of these. Thanks for your time

Comment: You are importing the json data as `import { universities } from '../pages/api/universities';`, try to import `import universities from '../pages/api/universities';` instead.

Comment: I did this but its not working, What Can I do now?

Comment: The same error or now is a different error?

Comment: error is map is not defined. Thank you

Comment: Can you please modify your code in the question with @GabrielAsakawa's suggestion? Also, which line is throwing the error?